# Why Delphi GDI+ Doesnt Support .Fon Fonts?

Tags: delphi, winapi, gdi+

Loading TTF Fonts success always:

```
var 
  FontFamily ! TGPFontFamily;
Begin                                //TTF
  FontFamily := TGPFontFamily.Create('Arial');//Load Status: OK.
End;
```

But loading fon lead to : Font Family not found!!

```
var 
  FontFamily ! TGPFontFamily;
Begin                              //.Fon
  FontFamily := TGPFontFamily.Create('ai');// Load Status: Font Family not found.
End;
```

i have tested many .Fon fonts but no success. 
any help will be apreciated.

Comment: .FON fonts are very old. I don't think GDI+ supports these bitmapped fonts.

Comment: I can only find references that says GDI+ supports TrueType (.TTF/.TTC/.OTF) fonts.

Comment: FWIW, what is the `!` in `FontFamily ! TGPFontFamily` ?

Comment: its SO fail encoding. i wrote it: ":" or maybe the modification turned it to "!".

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a Delphi limitation. Rather GDI+ has no support for bitmap fonts.

Comment: Is there any link from MS saying that? so i can stop searching.

Comment: I've not found an official MS link.

Comment: i saw an aplication using fon files and gdi+; so that what makes me do my research
so the conclusion:
1- its Support. or 2- There is a trick.

Comment: You can display bitmaps with GDI+. So you can decode the bitmap from the bitmap font and display that. But you cannot use GDI+ font objects and GDI+ text API with bitmap fonts.

Comment: is there any examples with delphi?

Comment: I don't know. You could do a websearch as readily as me. I just answered the question that you asked.